# Django: Assign Route to Order Based on User Input of Location

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In my create order view, I am trying to automatically assign the respective route based on the location the user inputs. Basically, every location in the system has a FK to a route. There are many locations within a route. If you select a location to send products to, the route should automatically be tied to.

Currently I am able to see the route for an order in my order_list.html page, but when I view the order in the Django admin, the route is not assigned to the order but the location is.

I want it to work similarly to how you would assign the current logged in user to an order:

```
form.instance.user = request.user
```

I tried using:

```
form.instance.company = request.user.company
```

But I am getting an attribute error:

> 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'location'

Here is my full `order_create` function:

orders/views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='account_login')
def order_create(request):
    """
    A function that takes the users cart with products, then converts the cart into an
    OrderForm. Then saves the form/order to the database.
    """
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.company = request.user.company
            form.instance.route = request.location.route
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                         product=item['product'],
                                         price=item['price'],
                                         quantity=item['quantity'])
            # clear the cart
            cart.clear()
            return render(request,
                          'orders/order/created.html',
                          {'order': order,
                           })
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    return render(request,
                  'orders/order/create.html',
                  {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

Here are the `Location`, `Route` and `Order` models:

orders/models.py:

```
class Route(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Locations(models.Model):
    """
    A model to represent a location or locations a company has.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    store_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Locations, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    delivery_date = models.DateField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and then finally the company and user model in my accounts app that are used as foreign keys in the orders app.

accounts/models.py:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    """
    A model to represent companies that can operate within the system, which multiple users are apart of.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    state = USStateField()
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    admin = models.ForeignKey("accounts.User", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,         related_name="company_admin", blank=True, null=True)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    A model to represent a User of the system.
    """
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('ADMIN', "Admin"),
        ('MANAGER', "Manager"),
        ('DRIVER', "Driver"),
        ('PRODUCTION', "Production")
    )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, help_text="(123)-123-1234", blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: If every `Location` has a FK to `Route`, then in your `Order` model you can/should remove the FK to `Route`, because it is redundant.

Comment: That makes sense. However, Im still struggling trying to find a way to autofill the route given the user input of the location. When I list out the orders, I can see the route tied to the order...but when I view the order in the Django admin, the route is not being saved to the order.